# how to add social share buttons below the image in WordPress post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am using Janah Theme, It gives me option to add social media sharing buttons in two locations, above & below post. But I want to know how to add it below the image inside the post?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your page builder. If you are using elememtor plugin you can find shortcode at the left side of your page inside the elememtor page builder. You can also use other page builder to get a shortcode snippet.

add the snippet and include the shortcode anywhere you want it to be visible
just like this